# to_crs("epsg:4326") retruns different coordinate

Tags: geopandas, shapely, pyproj

I am trying to change coordinates system on my geopandas dataframe from epsg:5179 to epsg:4236.

BUT, `.to_crs("epsg:4326")` retruns different coordinates... How can I get true cordinates?

```
geo[geometry].set_crs("epsg:5179", inplace = True)
geo_df = geo[geometry].to_crs("epsg:4326")


Original
LINESTRING (14138122.900 4519000.200, 14138248...LINESTRING (14135761.800 4518881.600, 14135799...

Changed-proj
LINESTRING (-149.90927 12.31701, -149.90912 12...LINESTRING (-149.91219 12.32162, -149.91215 12...
```

Comment: What is your `true coordinates`? What is its `CRS`?

Comment: The point of changing the CRS is to the get the locations of the geometries in a different coordinate system. You will by definition get different numeric values for the x- and y- coordinates of the geometries. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @PaulH  I have two data-frames. The one is following the epssg:5179 format, and the other is following epsg:4326. So that, I am trying to set in the same coordinate system format(epsg:4326)

Comment: Looks like you've achieved that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you got true coordinates with your code which is :

```
geo[geometry].set_crs("epsg:5179", inplace = True)
geo_df = geo[geometry].to_crs("epsg:4326")
```

I've been looking through `pyproj`, and couldn't find error to change coordinates `epsg:5179` to `epsg:4326`.

If you want to get futher more information about cordinates, you can visit [here](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/).